# Using vim as a git commit message writer, is it possible to autocomplete modified function names?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit

I find myself often repeating the names of the functions I've edited, in the commit message, and it'd be nice to have autocompletion for the functions I've just changed when writing the commit messasges.

Is it possible to get vim to somehow search through the current commited files and grab the function names, or better yet, only the modified ones?

I'm using gVim7.3 and C#, if that's at all relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the `-v` option to `git commit` that will cause git to place the diff of what you're committing in the file used to create the commit message. With most languages the headers of hunks within that diff will indicate the name of the function being modified. This will make the names of modified functions available for completing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

To simplify this I long ago did

```
git config --global alias.ci 'commit -v'
```

And always use `git ci` rather than `git commit`.

Newer versions of git support configuration to turn this on for all commits.

```
git config --global commit.verbose true
```

Comment: Wondering how can I put a patch there when rebasing (i.e. when editor is opened automatically after git squashed a series of commits).

Answer (score 5):

Vim 7.3 ships with `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`, which defines a `:DiffGitCached` command to show the differences you're about to commit. Once you have that in a split window, the default `<C-N>` completion (assuming default `'complete'` values) will pick those strings up automatically. (It's also good for a last check that you're really committing the right stuff.)

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working, but I can see how it might work for someone else. I think it was because I'm using mysysgit or something that would cause git bash to not have the same `$VIMRUNTIME` as when I use gvim outside of bash. +1